# How can I use hyper::client from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, hyper, rust-tokio

I have multiple threads performing some heavy operations and I need to use a client in middle of work. I'm using Hyper v0.11 as a HTTP client and I would like to reuse the connections so I need to share the same `hyper::Client` in order to keep open the connections (under `keep-alive` mode).

The client is not shareable among threads (it doesn't implement `Sync` or `Send`). Here a small snippet with the code I've tried to do:

```
let mut core = Core::new().expect("Create Client Event Loop");
let handle = core.handle();

let remote = core.remote();

let client = Client::new(&handle.clone());

thread::spawn(move || {

    // intensive operations...

    let response = &client.get("http://google.com".parse().unwrap()).and_then(|res| {
        println!("Response: {}", res.status());
        Ok(())
    });

    remote.clone().spawn(|_| {
        response.map(|_| { () }).map_err(|_| { () })
    });

    // more intensive operations...
});
core.run(futures::future::empty::<(), ()>()).unwrap();
```

This code doesn't compile:

```
thread::spawn(move || {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ within `[closure@src/load-balancer.rs:46:19: 56:6 client:hyper::Client<hyper::client::HttpConnector>, remote:std::sync::Arc<tokio_core::reactor::Remote>]`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::rc::Weak<std::cell::RefCell<tokio_core::reactor::Inner>>`

thread::spawn(move || {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ within `[closure@src/load-balancer.rs:46:19: 56:6 client:hyper::Client<hyper::client::HttpConnector>, remote:std::sync::Arc<tokio_core::reactor::Remote>]`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<hyper::client::pool::PoolInner<tokio_proto::util::client_proxy::ClientProxy<tokio_proto::streaming::message::Message<hyper::http::MessageHead<hyper::http::RequestLine>, hyper::Body>, tokio_proto::streaming::message::Message<hyper::http::MessageHead<hyper::http::RawStatus>, tokio_proto::streaming::body::Body<hyper::Chunk, hyper::Error>>, hyper::Error>>>>`
...
remote.clone().spawn(|_| {
               ^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `futures::Future<Error=hyper::Error, Item=hyper::Response> + 'static`
```

Is there any way to reuse the same client from different threads or some other approach?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no, but it's better that way.

Each `Client` object holds a pool of connections. Here's how Hyper's [`Pool`](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/v0.11.0/src/client/pool.rs#L14-L16) is defined in version 0.11.0:

```
pub struct Pool<T> {
    inner: Rc<RefCell<PoolInner<T>>>,
}
```

As `inner` is reference-counted with an `Rc` and borrow-checked in run-time with `RefCell`, the pool is certainly not thread-safe. When you tried to move that `Client` to a new thread, that object would be holding a pool that lives in another thread, which would have been a source of data races.

This implementation is understandable. Attempting to reuse an HTTP connection across multiple threads is not very usual, as it requires synchronized access to a resource that is mostly I/O intensive. This couples pretty well with Tokio's asynchronous nature. It is actually more reasonable to perform multiple requests in the same thread, and let Tokio's core take care of sending messages and receiving them asynchronously, without waiting for each response in sequence. Moreover, computationally intensive tasks can be executed by a CPU pool from `futures_cpupool`. With that in mind, the code below works fine:

```
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate futures;
extern crate futures_cpupool;

use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use hyper::client::Client;
use futures::Future;
use futures_cpupool::CpuPool;

fn main() {

    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();
    let client = Client::new(&handle.clone());
    let pool = CpuPool::new(1);

    println!("Begin!");
    let req = client.get("http://google.com".parse().unwrap())
        .and_then(|res| {
            println!("Response: {}", res.status());
            Ok(())
        });
    let intensive = pool.spawn_fn(|| {
        println!("I'm working hard!!!");
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        println!("Phew!");
        Ok(())
    });

    let task = req.join(intensive)
        .map(|_|{
            println!("End!");
        });
    core.run(task).unwrap();
}
```

If the response is not received too late, the output will be:

```
Begin!
I'm working hard!!!
Response: 302 Found
Phew!
End!
```

If you have multiple tasks running in separate threads, the problem becomes open-ended, since there are multiple architectures feasible. One of them is to delegate all communications to a single actor, thus requiring all other worker threads to send their data to it. Alternatively, you can have one client object to each worker, thus also having separate connection pools.

Comment: thanks for your response!! I'm not agreed on the fact that reusing connections from different threads is not usable, I say, if you have an schema based in futures (similar to Scala with Akka HTTP), you could hold a bunch of futures and some of them could depend on a request. This works well in tokio if you have all in the same event loop, but you don't have an easy way to have several threads submitting tasks like request http to an external event loop.

Comment: You haven't described what your many threads would be doing. So far it sounds like an XY problem. Have you considered moving the outcome of those multithreaded tasks to the client's thread, rather than the other way around?

Comment: Yes, that's right, This is the use case: I'm building a minimalistic load balancer, with some encryption and decryption operations (mainly that is the intensive operation), and the first approach I thought was to have an event loop to receive connections, a thread pool to handle the connections and n event loops as HTTP client. I found it very difficult to achieve, so for now I'm only have N event loops and each one receive tcp connections, decrypts a token. and perform some requests. But I think that this is not the better way to go.

Comment: _"an event loop to receive connections"_ is one tokio core, that part would be fine. The rest doesn't sound like something that can be addressed here without a new, specific question. As far as Hyper goes, a `Client` is not thread-safe and wrapping it around thread synchronization mechanisms is simply a bad idea.